# Flexible Insert STORED PROCEDURE

Tags: sql

my stored

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDynamicFun]
    @TblName nvarchar(max),@F1 nvarchar(50),@F2 nvarchar(50),@F3 nvarchar(50),@F4 nvarchar(50)
                          ,@P1 nvarchar(50),@P2 nvarchar(50),@P3 nvarchar(50),@P4 nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
declare @TAblE nvarchar(max);


set @TAblE = 'Insert Into ' + @TblName + '('+@F1+','+@F2+','+@F3+','+@F4+')Values ('+@P1+','+@P2+','+@P3+','+@P4+')'
    exec(@TAblE)
END
```

Display Error

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'Value of @P2'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'Value of @P3'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'Value of @P4'.
```

but @P1 Did not show her fault
 I want to save the data in any table by pass The Parameter to stored PROCEDURE
and  Taking into account the numeric fields

Comment: check your F1, F2, F3 variables

Comment: Such a procedure is an horrible idea. For one, it's wide open to SQL Injection (which cannot be avoided here). If you really want such flexibility, just submit the `INSERT` from the client, or make particular procedures for each table.

Comment: As mentioned above, this stored procedure may be dangerous but if you want to stay with this approach, add a two simple-quotes around every values. Here is an example: `VALUES (''' + @P1 + ''',''' + @P2...`

Comment: @JoëlSalamin that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that `@F1, @F2,...` are correctly set?

Comment: @Alejandro While it is a horrible idea, it is properly doable with [`quotename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-uis/library/ms176114.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This error is becase one of your parameter in :

@F1 , @F2 , @F3, @F4 may contain the value as :

```
'Value of @P2'
```

or `'Value of @P3'`

or  `Value of @P3`

or   `Value of @P4`

which are not your column names for `@TblName`.

Please check the values of your parameters mentioned above by using :

```
print @F1

print @F2

print @F3

print @F4
```

This will let you know the exact problem.

Comment: The problem is that the data, which are packaged show, but digital is the text

Comment: @MohamedAL-Hlwany cant understand u...plz be clear ... what are the values of F1,F2... ???